# WireSharkでTCP通信をキャプチャしたところ、重複ACKを4回以上受け取っていて、Fast Retransmissionが行われていませんでした。なぜでしょうか？

Tags: tcp, wireshark

## 背景

[TCP技術入門](https://gihyo.jp/book/2019/978-4-297-10623-2)を読んで、TCPについて勉強しています。
4.3章「プロトコルアナライザー「Wireshark」実践入門」に従って、FTP通信をWireSahrkでキャプチャしました。

## キャプチャしたFTP通信

### 環境

- OS: ubuntu/xenial64
- TCP輻輳制御アルゴリズム：`net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=reno`
- IPアドレス：

  - guest1: 192.168.33.10
  - guest2: 192.168.33.20

以下のVagrantfileを使って仮想マシンを起動しました。
https://github.com/neko9laboratories/tcp-book/blob/master/wireshark/vagrant/Vagrantfile

### 操作手順

1. `vagrant ssh guest1`でguest1にログインする。
2. WireSahrkを起動している状態で、以下のFTPコマンドを実行する。

```
open 192.168.33.20
user vagrant vagrant
prompt
put tempfile
```

https://github.com/neko9laboratories/tcp-book/blob/master/wireshark/ftp_conf.txt

## 質問

WireSharkのフィルタ条件を`tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack`にして、重複ACKの通信を確認したところ、送信側`192.168.33.10`は重複ACKを4回以上受け取っていました。
[image: FTP通信 重複ACKが4回以上]

なぜ重複ACKを4回以上受け取っているのでしょうか？
私は、下図のように（[パケットキャプチャの教科書](https://www.sbcr.jp/product/4797390711/)のサンプルデータ`tcp_duplicate_ack.pcapng`）、重複ACKを3回受け取ったら、Fast Retransmissionが行われることを期待していました。
[image: サンプルデータ tcp_duplicate_ack.pcapng]

またwiresharkのフィルタ条件を`tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission`にしたころ、絞り込み結果は0件でした。
なぜFast Retransmissionは行われないのでしょうか？

[TCP Retransmit・DupACK・Fast Retransmit ～トラブルシューティング時のキーワード～](https://troushoo.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-111.html) には、以下のように記載されていたので、もしかしたらOS設定の問題なのかもしれません。「重複ACK何回受け取ったらFast Retransmissionを行う」という設定は、どこで確認できるのでしょうか？

> 補足：
> この「DupACKを複数回受け取る」の”複数回”の回数は、Windows Server 2003では、初期値は2です。
> また変更することも可能で、レジストリ値”TcpMaxDupAcks”で設定もできます。
> 詳細は、Microsoft社のサイト「TcpMaxDupAcks」をご確認ください。
> (Vista以降のOSについてのMicrosoftからの情報は見つけることができませんでした。)

## 補足情報

参考情報としてTCP Stream Graphsを添付します。
[image: Sequence Numbers]
[image: Window Scaling]

## 参考にしたサイト

https://troushoo.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-111.html
https://milestone-of-se.nesuke.com/knowhow/wireshark/wireshark-tcp-error/