# ゲストOS間のTCP通信で重複ACKを確認しました。インターネットを介していないのに、なぜ重複ACKが発生するのでしょうか？

Tags: tcp, wireshark

## 背景

[TCP技術入門](https://gihyo.jp/book/2019/978-4-297-10623-2)を読んで、TCPについて勉強しています。
4.3章「プロトコルアナライザー「Wireshark」実践入門」に従って、FTP通信をWireSahrkでキャプチャしました。

## キャプチャしたFTP通信

### 環境

- OS: ubuntu/xenial64
- TCP輻輳制御アルゴリズム：`net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=reno`
- IPアドレス：

  - guest1: 192.168.33.10
  - guest2: 192.168.33.20
- VirtualBox

  - ネットワークアダプタのモード：内部ネットワーク

以下のVagrantfileを使って仮想マシンを起動しました。
https://github.com/neko9laboratories/tcp-book/blob/master/wireshark/vagrant/Vagrantfile

### 操作手順

1. `vagrant ssh guest1`でguest1にログインする。
2. WireSahrkを起動している状態で、以下のFTPコマンドを実行する。

```
open 192.168.33.20
user vagrant vagrant
prompt
put tempfile
```

https://github.com/neko9laboratories/tcp-book/blob/master/wireshark/ftp_conf.txt

## 質問

WireSharkでTCP通信を確認したところ、重複ACKの通信がありました。
[image: 重複ACK]
重複ACKを受け取ったということは、TCPセグメントが喪失されたということになると思います。

2つのゲストOS間で通信しているのに、なぜTCPセグメントが消失するのでしょうか？
インターネットを通る通信なら、ネットワークの輻輳によりTCPセグメントが消失するのは理解できます。
ローカル内での通信なら、ネットワークの輻輳は発生しないので、TCPセグメントも消失しないと考えています。

## 補足情報

参考情報としてTCP Stream Graphsを添付します。
[image: Sequence Numbers]
[image: Window Scaling]

## 参考情報

[重複ACKに関する別の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/85715)